# DirectoryNotFoundException when accessing ProgramData on Vista - Could not find a part of the path - WinIOError

Tags: c#, .net-2.0

Occasionally some users of our software report issues that are caused by wired `DirectoryNotFoundException` exceptions. This happens only to some users running Vista. Not all users running Vista have this problem. There were no reports of this issue from users running Win7 or XP (however that does not prove that this issue does not happen on these systems - we just don't have such reports).

Our software stores some graphics data inside ProgramData folder. When program tries to read those files the following exception is thrown:

```
Message: Could not find a part of the path 'C:\ProgramData\My App Name\Subfolder\Subfolder'.
mscorlib
   in System.IO.__Error.WinIOError(Int32 errorCode, String maybeFullPath)
   in System.IO.Directory.InternalGetFileDirectoryNames(String path, String userPathOriginal, String searchPattern, Boolean includeFiles, Boolean includeDirs, SearchOption searchOption)
   in System.IO.Directory.GetFiles(String path, String searchPattern, SearchOption searchOption)
   in System.IO.Directory.GetFiles(String path)
```

The path is *C:\ProgramData\My App Name\Subfolder\Subfolder*. Folder exists - I'm 100% sure. It was created by NSIS installer. It's writeable to all users (or at least it should be as that's how we set it with NSIS script). User confirms that the folder exists - he is able to navigate to that location using Windows Explorer.

At first I thought it was the UAC issue, but the exception says **Could not find a part of the path**. This drives me crazy as we are unable to reproduce the issue on our test systems. No matter the configuration. XP, Vista, Win7 - on our machines it just works.

Comment: Have you tried doing a simple if (!File.Exists(path)) statement right before this line of code just in case .NET can't read the file?

Comment: "The path is C:\ProgramData\My App Name\Subfolder\Subfolder. Folder exists - I'm 100% sure. It was created by NSIS installer." Are you 100% sure because you are relying on NSIS installer, or because on the machine in question you are able to start --> run --> "C:\ProgramData\My App Name\Subfolder\Subfolder" and actually view the folder contents that way?

Comment: @AJ. - user confirmed that he's able to navigate to that path using windows explorer. I saw the screenshot.

Comment: @Josh - it's not a matter of "if exists" - I can handle the exception. The problem is that the exception is thrown even if that folder exists - or at least it seems that it exists as user is able to navigate to that location using Windows Explorer.

Comment: @SiliconMind But if you do the test and the user can still navigate to the folder, doesn't that imply that the security settings that the application is running under doesn't have permission to access the folder?  Have you thought about doing a security demand (CodeAccessPermission.Demand )?

Comment: @Josh - the exception is `DirectoryNotFoundException`, not the `UnauthorizedAccessException`. Besides, user confirms that the folder in question has all privileges checked for "Users\machine". My first thought was that this is the UAC issue, but exception says "Not found".

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Finally we found a user that had the same issue and was willing to help with testing. The root cause of this error seems to be the NSIS installer which creates folder with one wrong character. No one noticed that because that char looks almost identical to the one that was supposed to be created. So `DirectoryNotFoundException` was indeed right.

The NSIS was supposed to create a folder with **ń** char

```
// U+0144   ń   c5 84   LATIN SMALL LETTER N WITH ACUTE
```

but instead created a folder with **ñ** char

```
// U+00F1   ñ   c3 b1   LATIN SMALL LETTER N WITH TILDE
```

The wired part is that happens only on some machines and we could not reproduce that.

Lesson for today: never fully trust your users when it comes to debugging. Even screenshot provided by the user was misleading as it displayed only contents of the folder in question.

Comment: Possible solution: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/10189227/nsis-installer-creates-directory-using-wrong-character-set