# NSIS installer creates directory using wrong character set

Tags: windows, character-encoding, nsis

On some machines my NSIS installer creates folder with one wrong character.

The NSIS was supposed to create a folder with **ń** char

```
// U+0144   ń   c5 84   LATIN SMALL LETTER N WITH ACUTE
```

but instead created a folder with **ñ** char

```
// U+00F1   ñ   c3 b1   LATIN SMALL LETTER N WITH TILDE
```

The wired part is that happens only on some machines and I could not reproduce that. As far as I can tell this was reported only for Windows Vista (possibly basic edition).

I suspect that this has something to do with Windows-1250 to UTF conversion. Because NSIS still does not support UTF, I'm using Windows-1250 encoded script file. The *ń* char is `0xF1` and should be translated to UTF `U+c584`, but instead the installer creates folder with `U+c3b1` char. On the other hand the `U+c3b1` is equivalent of Windows-1252 `0xF1`.

What may affect the interpretation of characters used in NSIS script, when compiled installer runs? How to assure expected conversion `0xF1` => `U+c584`?

Comment: To make things clear - I would not like to use uNSIS branch as it still has some unresolved issues. I'm patiently waiting for official NSIS 2.50 release. And boy, I'm waiting since 2009!

Comment: What unresolved issues do you have with NSISU? I haven't had any problems with it; it's all we use now at PortableApps.com.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The encoding of the NSIS source script does not really decide the final string, the translation of bytes from the script/installer to a unicode string happens on the end users system, therefore characters outside ASCII can vary based on the systems default codepage ([Language for non-Unicode programs (System Locale)](http://windows.microsoft.com/en-US/windows-vista/Change-the-system-locale)).

You can try to create a custom [LangString](http://anders_k.users.sourceforge.net/public/NSIS/2.46/Manual.html#langstring) for this directory name. For this to work you have to set your editors codepage to the problematic codepage when typing the ń. You can probably emulate this by checking $LANGUAGE (or use `System::Call kernel32::GetACP()i.r0` and check $0) in .onInit and StrCpy a string that translates correctly on this system into the problematic variable.

The next NSIS version will probably be v3.0, I don't know where you got 2.50 from but it is probably just a placeholder used by the unicode fork.

Comment: I'm starting to doubt that we will ever see next NSIS release. The 2.50 version number is from NSIS docs which seems to be way ahead of official release: http://nsis.sourceforge.net/Docs/Chapter1.html#1.4 - heck these even refer to working unicode support.

Comment: @SiliconMind: The online docs are from SVN trunk. You can compile a working unicode version today from trunk but it is pretty similar to the fork so you might as well just use that.